# Truncate string in Julia

Tags: string, julia

Is there a convenience function for truncating strings to a certain length?

It would equivalent to something like this

```
test_str = "test"
if length(test_str) > 8
   out_str = test_str[1:8]
else
   out_str = test_str
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by a certain length?  A certain number of characters? Or a certain character width?  They're different.

Comment: Certain number of characters

Comment: So, to summarize all of the very astute answers from talented programmers - no, there is not currently a "convenience function" that does this - however, there are several good options for *inconvenience* functions that will accomplish this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the naive ASCII world:

```
truncate_ascii(s,n) = s[1:min(sizeof(s),n)]
```

would do. If it's preferable to share memory with original string and avoid copying SubString can be used:

```
truncate_ascii(s,n) = SubString(s,1,min(sizeof(s),n))
```

But in a Unicode world (and it is a Unicode world) this is better:

```
truncate_utf8(s,n) = SubString(s,1, (eo=endof(s) ; neo=0 ; 
  for i=1:n 
    if neo<eo neo=nextind(s,neo) ; else break ; end ;
  end ; neo) )
```

Finally, @IsmaelVenegasCastelló reminded us of grapheme complexity (arrrgh), and then this is what's needed:

```
function truncate_grapheme(s,n)
    eo = endof(s) ; tt = 0 ; neo=0
    for i=1:n
        if (neo<eo)
            tt = nextind(s,neo)
            while neo>0 && tt<eo && !Base.UTF8proc.isgraphemebreak(s[neo],s[tt])
                (neo,tt) = (tt,nextind(s,tt))
            end
            neo = tt
        else
            break
        end
    end
    return SubString(s,1,neo)
end
```

These last two implementations try to avoid calculating the `length` (which can be slow) or allocating/copying, or even just looping `n` times when the `length` is shorter.

*This answer draws on contributions of @MichaelOhlrogge, @FengyangWang, @Oxinabox and @IsmaelVenegasCastelló*

Comment: `truncate_utf8` is the best choice unless grapheme issues are expected. There might even be more complexity lurking with Unicode. For example, _normalization_ which turns ligatures (e.g. "fi" pair) into two characters, so the `n` character prefix might not be a simple substring. `utf8` should suffice but familiarity with these issues is good to maintain.

Answer (score 4):

I would do `strtruncate(str, n) = join(take(str, n))`.

Example:

```
julia> strtruncate("αβγδ", 3)
"αβγ"

julia> strtruncate("αβγδ", 5)
"αβγδ"
```

Note that your code is not fully valid for Unicode strings.

Comment: What about `SubString()` will it also not perform reliably on Unicdoe strings?

Comment: `SubString` constructor still needs to handle Unicode index finding. This works for me: `strtruncate(str, n) = n>=length(str) ? str : SubString(str,1,chr2ind(str,n))`

Comment: The string methods in Julia (including `SubString`) work on indices into the underlying, not on characters. So there is no way to get the first 8 characters without actually iterating through them. e.g. see `SubString("",1,8)`, which is probably not what you might expect.

Comment: Oh yeah, there is also @DanGetz' approach of using `chr2ind`. That might be more performant.

Comment: @FengyangWang Actually it is not more performant (possibly in the future). Currently, the need for `length` (which iterates through the string) makes this similar to the iterator in the answer. Still the allocation is small and of fixed size in this approach.

Comment: Both `chr2ind` and `length` are doing iteration in your solution (some wasted work there). But the copy is being avoided. Benchmarking may show it to be faster.

Comment: BTW, it's possible to avoid the double iteration by `try`-ing the `chr2ind`. This will introduce constant overhead, but will remove the call to `length` which could very well be the most expensive part if the string is long but n is small.

Comment: The best way would be to loop and count valid indices until `n`.

Comment: Maybe this belongs on GitHub, but OP's objective seems reasonable and relatively common.  Given that, at given the complications that arise with what I would have thought would be the more simple and intuitive solutions, should one of these solutions that Fengyang and @Dan have suggested be added as a function to Base Julia?

Comment: Perhaps a `substring` function (which was my natural go-to name I tried with autocomplete at the REPL). [last comment - as this should probably be moved to github]

Comment: I would use `graphemes`, something like: `truncate(str::String, n) = String(collect(graphemes(str))[1:n])`

Comment: Sorry hadn't tested, actually that would be: `Base.truncate(str::String, n::Int)::String = join(collect(graphemes(str))[1:n])` ...tested! :D

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `graphemes` function:

```rb
C:\Users\Ismael
λ julia5
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  By greedy hackers for greedy hackers.
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?help" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _' |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.5.0-rc3+0 (2016-08-22 23:43 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |  x86_64-w64-mingw32

help?> graphemes
search: graphemes

  graphemes(s) -> iterator over substrings of s

  Returns an iterator over substrings of s that correspond to the extended
  graphemes in the string, as defined by Unicode UAX #29.
  (Roughly, these are what users would perceive as single characters, even
  though they may contain more than one codepoint; for example a letter 
  combined with an accent mark is a single grapheme.)
```

#### Example:

```rb
julia> s = "αβγπϕ1t_Ω₃!"; n = 8;

julia> length(s)
11

julia> graphemes(s)
length-11 GraphemeIterator{String} for "αβγπϕ1t_Ω₃!"

julia> collect(ans)[1:n]
8-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "α"
 "β"
 "γ"
 "π"
 "ϕ"
 "1"
 "t"
 "_"

julia> join(ans)
"αβγπϕ1t_"
```

Check out the `truncate` function:

```rb
julia> methods(truncate)
# 2 methods for generic function "truncate":
truncate(s::IOStream, n::Integer) at iostream.jl:43
truncate(io::Base.AbstractIOBuffer, n::Integer) at iobuffer.jl:140

help?> truncate
search: truncate

  truncate(file,n)

  Resize the file or buffer given by the first argument to exactly n bytes,
  filling previously unallocated space with '\0' if the file or buffer is 
  grown.
```

So the solution could look like this:

````rb
julia> @doc """
           truncate(s::String, n::Int)::String

       truncate a `String`; `s` up to `n` graphemes.

       # Example

       ```julia
       julia> truncate("αβγπϕ1t_Ω₃!", 8)
       "αβγπϕ1t_"

       julia> truncate("test", 8)
       "test"
       ```
       """ ->
       function Base.truncate(s::String, n::Int)::String
           if length(s) > n
               join(collect(graphemes(s))[1:n])
           else
               s
           end
       end
Base.truncate
````

Test it:

```rb
julia> methods(truncate)
# 3 methods for generic function "truncate":
truncate(s::String, n::Int64)
truncate(s::IOStream, n::Integer) at iostream.jl:43
truncate(io::Base.AbstractIOBuffer, n::Integer) at iobuffer.jl:140

help?> truncate
  truncate(file,n)

  Resize the file or buffer given by the first argument to exactly n bytes,
  filling previously unallocated space with '\0' if the file or buffer is 
  grown.

  truncate(s::String, n::Int)::String

  truncate a String; s up to n graphemes.

     Example
    ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> truncate("αβγπϕ1t_Ω₃!", 8)
  "αβγπϕ1t_"

  julia> truncate("test", 8)
  "test"

julia> truncate("αβγπϕ1t_Ω₃!", n)
"αβγπϕ1t_"

julia> truncate("test", n)
"test"
```

Profile it:

```rb
julia> Pkg.add("BenchmarkTools")
INFO: Nothing to be done
INFO: METADATA is out-of-date — you may not have the latest version of BenchmarkTools
INFO: Use `Pkg.update()` to get the latest versions of your packages

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @benchmark truncate("αβγπϕ1t_Ω₃!", 8)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     9
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%
  memory estimate:  1.72 kb
  allocs estimate:  48
  minimum time:     1.96 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      2.10 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        2.45 μs (7.80% GC)
  maximum time:     353.75 μs (98.40% GC)

julia> Sys.cpu_info()[]
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz:
        speed         user       nice        sys       idle        irq ticks
     2494 MHz     937640          0     762890   11104468     144671 ticks
```

Comment: The `truncate_grapheme` in my answer does only 1 allocation of 32 bytes (270ns median time - but this is computer dependent and mine is slower).

Answer (score 3):

If the string is ASCII, this is pretty efficient:

```
String(resize!(str.data, n))
```

Or in-place:

```
resize!(str.data, n)
```

For unicode, @Fengyang Wangs's method is very fast, but converting to a `Char` array can be slightly faster if you only truncate the very end of the string:

```
trunc1(str::String, n) = String(collect(take(str, n)))
trunc2(str::String, n) = String(Vector{Char}(str)[1:n])
trunc3(str::String, n) = String(resize!(Vector{Char}(str), n))
trunc4(str::String, n::Int)::String = join(collect(graphemes(str))[1:n])

function trunc5(str::String, n)
    if isascii(str)
        return String(resize!(str.data, n))
    else
        trunc1(str, n)
    end
end
```

Timing:

```
julia> time_trunc(100, 100000, 25)
  0.112851 seconds (700.00 k allocations: 42.725 MB, 7.75% gc time)
  0.165806 seconds (700.00 k allocations: 91.553 MB, 11.84% gc time)
  0.160116 seconds (600.00 k allocations: 73.242 MB, 11.58% gc time)
  1.167706 seconds (31.60 M allocations: 1.049 GB, 11.12% gc time)
  0.017833 seconds (100.00 k allocations: 1.526 MB)
true
julia> time_trunc(100, 100000, 98)
  0.367191 seconds (700.00 k allocations: 83.923 MB, 5.23% gc time)
  0.318507 seconds (700.00 k allocations: 132.751 MB, 9.08% gc time)
  0.301685 seconds (600.00 k allocations: 80.872 MB, 6.19% gc time)
  1.561337 seconds (31.80 M allocations: 1.122 GB, 9.86% gc time)
  0.061827 seconds (100.00 k allocations: 1.526 MB)
true
```

**Edit:** Whoops.. I just realized that I'm actually destroying the original string in `trunc5`. This should be correct, but with less superior performance:

```
function trunc5(str::String, n)
    if isascii(str)
        return String(str.data[1:n])
    else
        trunc1(str, n)
    end
end
```

New timings:

```
julia> time_trunc(100, 100000, 25)
  0.123629 seconds (700.00 k allocations: 42.725 MB, 7.70% gc time)
  0.162332 seconds (700.00 k allocations: 91.553 MB, 11.41% gc time)
  0.152473 seconds (600.00 k allocations: 73.242 MB, 9.19% gc time)
  1.152640 seconds (31.60 M allocations: 1.049 GB, 11.54% gc time)
  0.066662 seconds (200.00 k allocations: 12.207 MB)
true

julia> time_trunc(100, 100000, 98)
  0.369576 seconds (700.00 k allocations: 83.923 MB, 5.10% gc time)
  0.312237 seconds (700.00 k allocations: 132.751 MB, 9.42% gc time)
  0.297736 seconds (600.00 k allocations: 80.872 MB, 5.95% gc time)
  1.545329 seconds (31.80 M allocations: 1.122 GB, 10.02% gc time)
  0.080399 seconds (200.00 k allocations: 19.836 MB, 5.07% gc time)
true
```

**Aaand new edit:** Aargh, forgot the timing function. I'm inputting an ascii string:

```
function time_trunc(m, n, m_)
    str = randstring(m)
    @time for _ in  1:n trunc1(str, m_) end
    @time for _ in  1:n trunc2(str, m_) end
    @time for _ in  1:n trunc3(str, m_) end
    @time for _ in  1:n trunc4(str, m_) end
    @time for _ in  1:n trunc5(str, m_) end
    trunc1(str, m_) == trunc2(str, m_) == trunc3(str, m_) == trunc4(str, m_) == trunc5(str, m_)
end
```

**Final edit (I hope):**
Trying out @Dan Getz's `truncate_grapheme` and using unicode strings:

```
function time_trunc(m, n, m_)
    # str = randstring(m)
    str = join(["αβγπϕ1t_Ω₃!" for i in 1:100])
    @time for _ in  1:n trunc1(str, m_) end
    @time for _ in  1:n trunc2(str, m_) end
    @time for _ in  1:n trunc3(str, m_) end
    # @time for _ in  1:n trunc4(str, m_) end  # too slow
    @time for _ in  1:n trunc5(str, m_) end
    @time for _ in  1:n truncate_grapheme(str, m_) end
    trunc1(str, m_) == trunc2(str, m_) == trunc3(str, m_) == trunc5(str, m_) == truncate_grapheme(str, m_)
end
```

Timing:

```
julia> time_trunc(100, 100000, 98)
  0.690399 seconds (800.00 k allocations: 103.760 MB, 3.69% gc time)
  1.828437 seconds (800.00 k allocations: 534.058 MB, 3.66% gc time)
  1.795005 seconds (700.00 k allocations: 482.178 MB, 3.19% gc time)
  0.667831 seconds (800.00 k allocations: 103.760 MB, 3.17% gc time)
  0.347953 seconds (100.00 k allocations: 3.052 MB)
true

julia> time_trunc(100, 100000, 25)
  0.282922 seconds (800.00 k allocations: 48.828 MB, 4.01% gc time)
  1.576374 seconds (800.00 k allocations: 479.126 MB, 3.98% gc time)
  1.643700 seconds (700.00 k allocations: 460.815 MB, 3.70% gc time)
  0.276586 seconds (800.00 k allocations: 48.828 MB, 4.59% gc time)
  0.091773 seconds (100.00 k allocations: 3.052 MB)
true
```

So the last one seems clearly the best (and this post is now way too long.)

Comment: What's the input string?

Comment: Forgot the timing function. Added it now.

Comment: Can you time the versions in my answer too? (They should copy-paste OK)

Comment: Actually, when I cannot do `resize!` the whole thing falls apart a bit. Then you can just as well use `str[1:n]` and forget about accessing `str.data`. So the point of my answer is sort of gone.

Comment: The ascii version of your code is the same as mine. `str[1:n]` should be the same as `str.data[1:n]`. I'm not sure how to generate unicode strings.

Comment: `join(["αβ" for i=1:4])` should work, or copy pasting strings from @IsmaelVenegasCastelló

Comment: I didn't know about `randstring` thanks! Shouldn't `Base` have this API instead? `Base.rand(::Type{String})::String = randstring(); rand(String)`. So that it is consistent with the other methods.

Comment: Perhaps, but `rand` normally returns an array of whatever type you specify, so some people might expect an array of strings.

Comment: Of course, that could be something like: `rand(::Type{String}, n::Int)::Vector{String} = String[randstring() for i in 1:n]` for consistency, but completely generic with `rand(::Type{String}, dims::Int...)` and maybe other methods too.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
"test"[1:min(end,8)]
```

Also

```
 SubString("test", 1, 8)
```

Comment: Note that this will not work correctly with unicode strings.

Comment: You can probably fix that with `prevind`

Comment: @Oxinabox does `prevind()` even do anything besides subtract one from its second argument?  Maybe I just don't understand it.  When I use `prevind("test", 8)` I get `7` which doesn't seem to match with its description.

Comment: @MichaelOhlrogge the way strings are indexed now in Julia is confusing: they are a logically a mapping from {1,2,...,length(s)} to characters, but they are indexed as an array of bytes. This may give the feeling of speed because it reminds people of C langauge, but it just forces the coder to learn the lingo of accessing strings correctly in Julia (`prevind` and such).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that can handle any UTF-8 string:

```
function trim_str(str, max_length)
    edge = nextind(str, 0, max_length)
    if edge >= ncodeunits(str)
        str
    else
        str[1:edge]
    end
end
```